# How to keep the single quotation mark after using $* in bin/sh or bin/bash

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I'm using a shell script wrapper to execute clang while I met the problem when I get $* and use $CLANG to exec $CLANG $*, the problem is that the option '-DPACKAGE_VERSION="2.2.0-pre"' become -DPACKAGE_VERSION="2.2.0-pre" after the wrapper.

It shows the error:
clang-10: error: no such file or directory: '2.2.0-pre"'

My wrapper looks like:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

CLANG=${CLANG:-clang}

if [ `echo $* | grep -c "keyword"` -eq 1 ]; then
  exec $CLANG $*
else
  exec $CLANG $* -fsanitize=hextype
fi
```

Anyone has any idea to keep the single quotation mark after the bash?

Comment: `$*` is irredeemably broken. You should only ever use `"$@"` (including the double quotes; without them, it behaves just as badly as `$*`)

Comment: That said, `'-DPACKAGE_VERSION="2.2.0-pre"'` when parsed _as shell syntax_ contains the precise literal data `-DPACKAGE_VERSION="2.2.0-pre"`. The outer single quotes are syntax -- they aren't part of the data itself, so they aren't actually passed to clang..

Comment: ...that is to say, you _want_ some of the behaviors which are described as a common source of confusion in [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), so it's not a problem (for purposes of your current use case) that you're getting those behaviors.

Comment: The bug you _do_ probably have here is that you're trying to call `CLANGXX`, but no such variable is set; you only set `CLANG`. In that interpretation, the `clang-10:` in the error message is the $0 of your shell, so the shell is misrepresenting what executable it is. If you want to prove or disprove that, add `set -x` to your shell script to enable trace logging (or run `sh -x yourscript arg1 arg2 ...`), and add the resulting trace log to the question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : "$@" seems work, let me try and get back to you. For CLANGXX, I've updated the question, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: (I should have said "irredeedably broken _for this use case_" -- `"$*"` is useful when you want to coalesce a list into a string, combining them with the first character in `IFS` used as a separator; sometimes that's what one wants, but `$*` _outside quotes_ is almost always wrong, as in an unquoted context you're combining contents with the first character of IFS into a single string, _then splitting that single string back into separate words again_)

Comment: ...anyhow -- I still do need xtrace logs to understand the problem with enough depth to be able to write a comprehensive answer explaining how it came to manifest the specific symptom at hand.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : Yes, "$@" works well now, thanks!

Comment: @Crystal you can answer your own question, if you like.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @Charles Duffy, "$@" (including the double quotes) works in my case.